# startx error: no desktop manager

Tags: linux, kde, backtrack

I have Backtrack 5R2 KDE. The error resulted from a hard-reset (hard-reboot). After that, I cannot load the KDE manager when I enter the startx command after logging in.

Whenever I do a startx command (as root), the result resembles the following:

[image]

This is not the actual output (I just drew this with MS paint because I cannot do a printscreen). The screen is just black with the icon in the upper left corner. The other pop-up menu appears when left-clicking the mouse.

I tried the `cp xorg.conf.failsafe xorg.conf` advice from other websites with no luck.

I have also tried the 'reconfigure option(s)' form the recovery mode with no success.

============ UPDATE ===============

Here is an excerpt of /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
(EE) [drm] failed to open device
(EE) VESA: Kernel modesetting driver in use, refusing to load
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
(II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
(II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfbdevhw.so
(II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
  compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 0.0.2
  ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0

...
(EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
(EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
(EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
(EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
(EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
...
```

Comment: Were you root when you ran the command? What's the diff?

Comment: Yeah. Actually I did mention running startx as root.

Comment: The `cp` command; sorry. Can you diff the lousy conf with the failsafe conf and put that here?

Comment: `# diff xorg.conf.renamed xorg.conf.failsafe_renamed` returns nothing.

Comment: That means the issue is due to the differences between normal and recovery mode.

Comment: KDE usually comes with its own start script, which you could try instead of startx: "startkde"

Comment: when I tried startkde, I got: 'startkde' is currently not installed

Comment: That weird window manager you see is `fvwm`, an extremely basic window manager that loads by default... I don't think running `startx` is a good way to get to an X session; doesn't Backtrack have a display manager?

Comment: If you are referring to a desktop manager, it has. It got the KDE version. The system boots as text-only unless startx is issued to load the default manager.